# Python Voice assistant using tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I am creating a voice assistant and using tkinter as the user interface.
Is there a way I can be able to make the interface such that if the assistant speaks, a label appears showing that the assistant is speaking or if the assistant is listening it shows that the voice assistant is listening.
The output should be as shown  below. Such that if I press the Start button the label should show listening.

Any ideas or insights regarding this would be appreciated.

Here is my GUI code:

```
#Creating the main window 
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
wn = tk.Tk() 
wn.title("DataFlair Voice Assistant")
wn.geometry('700x300')
wn.config(bg='LightBlue1')
        
Label(wn, text='This Is Diva', bg='LightBlue1',
      fg='black', font=('Courier', 15)).place(x=50, y=10)


#Button to convert PDF to Audio form
Button(wn, text="Start", bg='gray',font=('Courier', 15), command=voice_command).place(x=290, y=100)

showCommand=StringVar(wn)

cmdLabel=Label(wn, textvariable=showCommand, bg='LightBlue1',
      fg='black', font=('Courier', 15))
cmdLabel.place(x=250, y=150)

#Runs the window till it is closed
wn.mainloop()
```

[image]

Comment: We need more information and in the best case a reproducible example to help you further. This question is way too broad.

Comment: Without seeing any code, its hard to even suggest a method

Comment: @DelriusEuphoria I provided the GUI Code